# How to make user input not case sensitive?

Tags: python

I want to create a function to filter which files I want to open and which months and day specifically. That way, the users need to input which city (files) they want to analyze on which particular month or day. However, I want the user to be able to input something that is not case sensitive.

For example, the user can input 'chicago'/'CHICAGO"/"ChIcAgO" and the it still give you the right output and not the error handling message. Here is the code I use:

```
def get_filters ():

    city_options = ['Chicago','New York City','Washington']
    month_options = ['January','February','March','April','May','June','All']
    day_options = ['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday','Sunday','All']
    while True:
        try:
            city = city_options.index(input('\nInsert name of the city to analyze! (Chicago, New York City, Washington)\n'))
            month = month_options.index(input('\nInsert month to filter by or "All" to apply no month filter! (January, February, etc.)\n'))
            day = day_options.index(input('\nInsert day of the week to filter by or "All" to apply no day filter! (Monday, Tuesday, etc.)\n'))
            return city_options[city].lower(), month_options[month].lower(), day_options[day].lower()
        except ValueError:
            print ("Your previous choice is not available. Please try again")

def load_data (city,month,day):
   
    #load data file into DataFrame
    df = pd.read_csv(CITY_DATA[city].lower())

    #convert start time column (string) to datetime
    df['Start Time']=pd.to_datetime(df['Start Time'])

    #create new column to extract month and day of the week from start time
    df['Month'] = df['Start Time'].dt.month
    df['Day_of_Week'] = df['Start Time'].dt.weekday_name

    #filter by month if applicable
    if month.lower()!= 'All':
        #use the index of the month list to get corresponding into
        months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June']
        month = months.index(month) + 1
        #filter by month to create new dataframes
        df = df[df['Month'] == month]

    if day.lower()!= 'All':
        #filter by day_of_week to create new DataFrames
        df =df[df['Day_of_Week'] == day]

    return(df)
```

Comment: The simplest way to make something case insensitive is to turn both values you need to compare to lower or upper case.

Comment: I tried did that but it's not working out. This is the result I got:

Insert Name Of The City To Analyze! (Chicago, New York City, Washington)
chicago
Your previous choice is not available. Please try again

Insert Name Of The City To Analyze! (Chicago, New York City, Washington)
ChICAgo
Your previous choice is not available. Please try again

Answer (score 6):

The best way to do so is just take the required input and convert it into the required case.

Use the inbuilt functions of python

```
variable.lower()
```

or

```
variable.upper()
```

Answer (score 6):

You should use `str.casefold` to remove case sensitivity. As per [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.casefold), this is stricter than `str.lower`:

> **str.casefold()**
>
> Return a casefolded copy of the string. **Casefolded strings may be used
>   for caseless matching.**
>
> Casefolding is similar to lowercasing but more aggressive because it
>   is intended to remove all case distinctions in a string. For example,
>   the German lowercase letter 'ß' is equivalent to "ss". Since it is
>   already lowercase, lower() would do nothing to 'ß'; casefold()
>   converts it to "ss".

For example:

```
x = 'ßHello'

print(x.casefold())

sshello
```

Answer (score 3):

I just started learning Python in December 2021.

I encountered a similar problem while writing the codes for a 'choose your own fantasy game".

To remove the case sensitivity, use the string.lower() or string.upper() function. Now, this answer is no different from the first answer to this question.

So, what's special here?

Well, if you are testing the answer from the user, your if-statement must have the same case as the case you are converting to e.g

1. answer = input("What is rat? 'Animal' or 'Food' ")

3)if answer.lower() == "animal":
print("Congratulations. You win! ")
5) else:
print("Sorry, you lose! ")

OR:

1. answer = input("What is rat? 'Animal' or 'Food' ")

3)if answer.upper() == "ANIMAL":
print("Congratulations. You win! ")
5) else:
print("Sorry, you lose! ")

N.B: No matter how the user types their answer (ANIMAL, ANimal, animal), if the answer is correct, he wins. So long the test case function is the same as the case string (line 3) to be tested.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I am new too but I think you should look at string functions. Presuming you use python 3 since you use input and get no ValueError, you can just add .lover().title() after the parentheses of the input

Example:

```
city = city_options.index(input('\nInsert name of the city to analyze! (Chicago, New York City, Washington)\n').lower().title())
```

Should do the trick as like If you input cHIcaGO it will be converted to Chicago instantly.

Hope it helps!

Edit:(After correcting misspelling of lower() function tried it on webbrowser, pycharm and Python itself. Works just fine for me(I'm using python 2.7 so I corrected all inputs as raw_input,If you are using python 3 you don't have to change them. ).)

Comment: I tried did that but it's not working out. This is the result I got: Insert Name Of The City To Analyze! (Chicago, New York City, Washington) chicago Your previous choice is not available. Please try again Insert Name Of The City To Analyze! (Chicago, New York City, Washington) ChICAgo Your previous choice is not available. Please try again

Comment: Sorry, misspelled .lower() function. :D Now It works